# MediaStreamAPI - Standard SampleRate

Tags: javascript, webrtc, web-audio-api

Defining a [sampleRate](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#widl-MediaTrackSupportedConstraints-sampleRate) will be available in future. At this moment what is the standard sampleRate when we capture audio from mic? When I put this audio in [WebAudioAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#Sample-rate) and use [sampleRate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/sampleRate) I always have 480000. So, 480000 is the standard of MediaStreamAPI? Or dependes of other factors?

Comment: For "local" MediaStream (getUserMedia): Depends on the hardware, according to specs.  From experience it is almost always 48000.  However, I've had some Android devices at 44100

Comment: @user120242 I change my sampleRate of mic in windows definitions. To very differente rates....But in audiocontext the sampleRate remains the same... 48000. Do you know why?

Comment: It does not necessarily depend on those settings.  It depends on what the hardware itself supports, favoring certain sample rates first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Web Audio, the default audio context sample rate is the sample rate (and clock) of the default output device.  The input is resampled to the output rate; so in short, the sample rate will be whatever the user's output device is.  It's frequently 44.1kHz on desktops, actually.

Comment: Thanks @cwilso. Meanwhile I found something to solve this problem: [link](https://github.com/jussi-kalliokoski/audiolib.js). The implementation is: `audioLib.Sink.resample(buffer_to_resample,audio_context_sampleRate/desirible_sampleRate)`

Comment: I change my sampleRate of mic in windows definitions. To very differente rates....But in audiocontext the sampleRate remains the same... 48000. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

The media stream / peer connection code may re-sample depending on the audio codec negotiated. So the sampling rate of the audio stream received by the remote peer in JS may not be the same as the "capturer" sampling rate. The audio sink might also re-sample when playing the stream as noted above.